# How to solve an ODE 4th order with matlab ode23s?

Tags: matlab, ode

actually I am trying to solve the following ODE by using ode23s. Unfortunately I don't really know how to do it.

The ode is given as:

```
bo(t)*y + b1(t)*y' + b2(t)*y'' + b3(t)*y''' + b4(t)*y''' = ao(t)*cst
```

(Those derivatives should be marked with dots 'cause, they're all time-derivatives, eg. y' = dy/dt, y'' = d2y/dt2 etc. The parameters bo, b1, ..., b4 and ao are given as matlab-functions. 'cst' is a constant.

First, I transformed this equation into a system of ODEs, what leads me to the following function:

```
function [dy] = odetest(y,cst,ao,bo,b1,b2,b3,b4)
  dy = [ y(2); ...
         y(3); ...
         y(4); ...
         (-b1*y(2) + ao*cst - b2*y(3) - b3*y(4) + bo*y(1))*(1/(b4)) ];
end
```

So ... to simplify the procedure (and as a first approximation) I want to hold the time-dependent parameters ao, bo, b1, ... b4 constant for each time step.

And now the problem starts: I don't know how to put this function in ode23s that it could be solved for an arbitrary timestep with given initial-conditions. Maybe I made a kind of mistake in the transformation of the time-derivatives ...

I guessed that the solution has to be something like, which unfortunately doesn't work

```
% file where the Ode has to be solved
% Loop over all time-steps

for i=1:number_timesteps

   time0 = i-1;
   time  = i;

   ao = function_ao(i); % function of parameter a, which is now constant in each timestep

   bo = function_bo(i);
   b1 = function_b1(i);
   b2 = function_b2(i);
   b3 = function_b3(i);
   b4 = function_b4(i);

   y = value1;   % initial conditions for y
   dy = value2;
   ddy = value3;
   dddy = value4;

   cst = value5; % value of cst in the actual timestep

   [T, Y] = ode23s(@odetest, [time0 time1] [y; dy; ddy; dddy], ...
   cst, ao, bo, b1, b2, b3, b4 ); % the arguments are the inital conditions, parameters ao, bo, ...

end
```

But ... I don't really understand what I did wrong. And I don't know either how to solve the problem if the parameters ao, bo, b1, ..., b4 change in one time-step, so that ode23s has to use their functions somehow.

It would be great if someone can help me. Thank you in advance!

**Edit - Implementation**

I now modified my code as follows, but unfortunately get an error "Error using odetest (line 5) Not enough input arguments." I don't know why :/

odetest.m:

```
    function [ dy ] = odetest( ttime, y, cst, ff1, ff2, ff3, ff4, ...
                  df1, df2, df3, df4, dd2, dd31, dd32, dd33, ...
                  dd34, ttk, tt0, EE1)

    EE0 = fe0(ff1, ff2, ff3, ff4, ttk, tt0, ttime);
    e1 = fe1(df1, dd2, dd31, ttk, tt0, ttime);
    e2 = fe2(df2, dd2, dd32, ttk, tt0, ttime);
    e3 = fe3(df3, dd2, dd33, ttk, tt0, ttime);
    e4 = fe4(df4, dd2, dd34, ttk, tt0, ttime);

    a0 = fa0(EE0, e1, e2, e3, e4);    
    b0 = fb0(e1, e2, e3, e4);
    b1 = fb1(EE0, EE1, EE1, EE1, EE1, e1, e2, e3, e4);
    b2 = fb2(EE0, EE1, EE1, EE1, EE1, e1, e2, e3, e4);
    b3 = fb3(EE0, EE1, EE1, EE1, EE1, e1, e2, e3, e4);
    b4 = fb4(EE0, EE1, EE1, EE1, EE1);

    dy = [ y(2); ...
           y(3); ...
           y(4); ...
           (-bb_1*y(2) + aa_0*cst - bb_2*y(3) - bb_3*y(4) + bb_0*y(1))*(1/(bb_4))];

end
```

The file itself, where I call this function is

```
% something before (set constant parameters val_i and define initial
% conditions yy_t0 for first step ...
for i=1:n

   dbl_t0 = t(i-1,1);
   dbl_t  = t(i,1);

   cst = act(i,1) - act(i-1);


   [T, Y] = ode23s(@odetest, [dbl_t0 dbl_t], [yy_t0 ...
            dyy_t0 ddy_t0 dddy_t0],cst, ...
            val_f1, val_f2, val_f3, val_f4, val_d1, val_d2, val_d3, val_d4, val_dd2, ...
            val_dk1, val_dk2, val_dk3, val_dk4, val_tk, val_t0, val_E1);

   yy_t = Y(1);
   dyy_t = Y(2);
   ddyy_t = Y(3);
   dddyy_t = Y(4);

   yy_t0 = yy_t;
   dyy_t0 = dyy_t;
   ddyy_t0 = ddyy_t;
   dddyy_t0 = dddyy_t;

end
```

... does anyone sees a mistake in here?

**Last Edit**

I found the mistake. - I have to call ode23s in the following way:

```
[T, Y] = ode23s(@(ttime,y)odetest(ttime, y, cst, ...
            f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4, d_11, d_12, d_13, d_14, d_2, d_31, ...
            d_32, d_33, d_34, t_k, t_0, E_1), [dbl_t0 dbl_t], ...
            [yy_t0 dyy_t0 ddyy_t0 dddyy_t0]);
```

... now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ode23s` for a single timestep, let it integrate for the whole time series and utilize your `odetest` function (Differential System function) to re-evaluate your parameter for each timestep. You will achieve better accuracy with this although it requires work on your part to ensure the parameter functions are setup correctly to work with the timespan you use. By the way, the first parameter of `ODEFUN` is time, not your state!

```
function [dy] = odetest(t, y, cst)
    ao = function_ao(t);
    b1 = function_b1(t);

    % ...re-evaluate all your parameters here...

    dy = [ y(2); ...
           y(3); ...
           y(4); ...
           (-b1*y(2) + ao*cst - b2*y(3) - b3*y(4) + bo*y(1))*(1/(b4)) ];
end

...

% Somewhere else in your code
y = value1;   % initial conditions for y
dy = value2;
ddy = value3;
dddy = value4;
[T, Y] = ode23s( @odetest, [0 number_of_timesteps], [y dy ddy dddy], cst );
```

This style is especially useful when switching solvers, since they will use different integration techniques that hop different time locations (they don't always integrate at specific time points).

If you wish to integrate at *specific* timepoints, you can also pass a timeseries ( `1:number_of_timesteps` ) instead of a timespan as shown above.

Comment: Hello Rollen D'souza,
thank you for your answer. - I will try it that way. There's now one question remaining: how is it now possible to tell ode23s not to change the parameters ao and b1 in every time-step?

If i have time-points given: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 (where for each time step 1-0, 2-1, 3-2, ... change the initial-conditions and the 'cst') ... - how can I ensure, that the parameters a0 and b1, ... are just changed at the beginning of every time step (according to those inital conditions) but don't change during the integration-routine that ode23s performs?

Comment: What do you mean by every time step? Timesteps by definition are the points in which you integrate, which is dependent on the integration routine. If you are concerned about *when* a value changes use your `t` value to determine when is the appropriate time to change the value. (i.e. make your parameters a piecewise function of `t`. Then it doesnt matter if they are reevaluated, they will only 'change' when you reach the appropriate time.)

Comment: Mmh, maybe I expressed it inaccurate: the ode describes a rheological model (generalized maxwell). I have a data-series with specific points in time and corresponding values for tension (= `cst`) to act on this model. These tensions change stepwise with every point in time but stay constant between them.
Thats why I thaught it is the best way to solve the ode for each time-step from my data-series and adapt the initial conditons (values at the end of a time-step are the initial-conditions for the next step ...). Otherwise I don't know, where ode23s gets its initial/transition-conditions from.

Comment: [i posted some additional things, concerning my problem ...]